# Pygame keeps giving me an error on a line that doesn't exist. Why is that?

Tags: python, class, module, pygame

So I put together a few classes in a file. My main file is called main.py, and it calls the classes in the file gameobjects.py. However, when I ran my code importing this file, I got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gameobjects import *
  File "/Users/number1son100/Desktop/Pygame game/gameobjects.py", line 12

                                                                   ^
```

The thing is, the file gameobjects.py only has 11 lines!!!

Here is the code for gameobjects.py:

```
import pygame
from imageloader import *

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, scale, clip):
        self.image = imageLoader(image, scale, (clip))

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, width, height):
        self.originalAsset = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.originalAsset, (width,height)
```

What is going on?

Comment: From looking at what you have posted, it looks like you are missing a closing parenthesis `)` at the end of your last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of your last line:

```
self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.originalAsset, (width,height)
```

Add a closing parenthesis and it should run fine:

```
self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.originalAsset, (width,height))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.originalAsset, (width,height) <- missing paren
```

Should be:

```
self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.originalAsset, (width,height))
```